# How to enumerate one align environment equations differently?

Tags: equations, numbering, align, amsmath

I have the following `align` environment to wrap a set of equations into a single group.

```
\begin{align}
AXA & = A \label{eq:5.4.1} \\
XAX & = X  \label{eq:5.4.2} \\
AX & = (AX)^T  \label{eq:5.4.3} \\ 
XA & = (XA)^T  \label{eq:5.4.4} \\
AX & = XA  \label{eq:5.4.5} \\
A^k & = XA^{k+1}, \; k = 0,1,2,\dots  \label{eq:5.4.6} \\
\end{align}
```

I would like to tag these aligned equations as (1), (2),..., so that I can refer in the document uniquely.

How to do that?

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
This equation should be counted usual. 
\begin{equation}
Some\_other\_equation
\end{equation}
The following should count as (1), (2), \dots, ....
  \begin{align}
AXA & = A \label{eq:5.4.1} \\
XAX & = X  \label{eq:5.4.2} \\
AX & = (AX)^T  \label{eq:5.4.3} \\ 
XA & = (XA)^T  \label{eq:5.4.4} \\
AX & = XA  \label{eq:5.4.5} \\
A^k & = XA^{k+1}, \; k = 0,1,2,\dots  \label{eq:5.4.6} \\
\end{align}

This equation should be counted usual. 
\begin{equation}
another\_equation
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Current Output:

[image]

### Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Do you want *all* numbers from (1) to (7), or only the first and the last ones, and vertical dots in between?

Comment: You want an environment to do this automatically? If not, then use `\begin{align*}` and add a `\tag{}` to each equation.

Comment: @Bernard All the numbers. I have put vdots to denote all the numbers should be there...means (1), (2), (3),... (8)..

Comment: Wouldn't be simpler to use the `subequations` environment, to number them as `(1.2a),(1.2b),…`? One also could number them as `(2a),(2b),…`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik this does not allow me to do the cross reference dynamically. By any chance if I had to change `\tag{1}` to `\tag{A1}`, I wont be able to reference the same in a long document.

Comment: @David Yes, you can. If you use, for example, `Eq.~\ref{eq:5.4.3}` the printed output will be `Eq. 3`. Of course, this would open the question on how confusing it would be to number an equation `Y` in a document where all equations are numbered `X.Y`. But the cross referencing works...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  When I have used `tag{1}` and the label together, it gave this error. `Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eq:5.4.2' will be lost. \end{align*}`

Comment: @David Works fine for me... I'll post an answer. If it doesn't work for you tell me and I'll delete it :)

Comment: @Bernard Your Suggestion seems to be working. However, I need to redefine the enumeration such that `(1.2_1), (1.2_2)...` since inside the document I need to write something like "if the equation (1.2_i) is satisfied for all $i\in {1,2,3,4}$, X is called {1,2,3,4}-inverse

Comment: @Bernard Kindly add your answer by redefining as above comment, if possible.

Comment: \David: I've posted a solution,that should correspond to what you'd like to have, if I've well understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\begin{align*}` to suppress the numbering there and use `\tag` to add the numbers manually:

> [image]

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
This equation should be counted usual.
\begin{equation}
\text{Some other equation}
\end{equation}
The following should count as (1), (2), \dots
\begin{align*}
AXA & = A \label{eq:5.4.1} \tag{1}\\
XAX & = X  \label{eq:5.4.2} \tag{2}\\
AX & = (AX)^T  \label{eq:5.4.3} \tag{3}\\
XA & = (XA)^T  \label{eq:5.4.4} \tag{4}\\
AX & = XA  \label{eq:5.4.5} \tag{5}\\
A^k & = XA^{k+1}, \; k = 0,1,2,\dots \label{eq:5.4.6} \tag{6}
\end{align*}
This equation should be counted usual. Reference to \ref{eq:5.4.3}
\begin{equation}
\text{another equation}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I also removed the extra `\\` from the last equation in `align*`.

Comment: It works perfectly now... I have no idea why there was an error when I have tried the same initially. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `subequations` environment, to have equation numbers in this group as `(1.2a), (1.2b),…`. If you prefer to number them as `(1.2₁),(1.2₂),…`, one can patch the environment. It works fine for cross-referencing, even with `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{subequations}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \protected@edef\theparentequation{\theequation}%
  \setcounter{parentequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \def\theequation{\theparentequation\textsubscript{$ \mkern1mu $\arabic{equation}}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{parentequation}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

This equation should be counted usual.
\begin{equation}
Some\_other\_equation
\end{equation}
The following should count as (1), (2), \dots, ....
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
AXA & = A \label{eq:5.4.1} \\
XAX & = X \label{eq:5.4.2} \\
AX & = (AX)^T \label{eq:5.4.3} \\
XA & = (XA)^T \label{eq:5.4.4} \\
AX & = XA \label{eq:5.4.5} \\
A^k & = XA^{k+1}, \; k = 0,1,2, ... \label{eq:5.4.6}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

These equations (\crefrange{eq:5.4.1}{eq:5.4.6}) should be counted usual.
\begin{equation}
another\_equation
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]